# Why does this single value SNMP OID have a bunch of sub-values?

Tags: snmp, juniper

I have a Juniper MIB in which this OID: `1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.24` corresponds to this value: `1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.2`.

When I run an snmpwalk of `1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.24` I get this:

```
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.1.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.2.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.2.1.2.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.4.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.4.1.2.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.4.1.3.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.4.1.4.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.4.1.5.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.7.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.8.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperating5MinAvgCPU.9.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 13
```

What's with all the extra stuff? Why isn't it just a single value? How would I be able to tell programatically which sub-value was relevant? Is there somewhere I can go read that would explain this result in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read more about tables in SNMP books, you should realize that `1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13` (aka `jnxOperatingTable`) is a table that contains data in tabular form.

Things like `.1.1.0.0` are the actual indexes of each rows, if you read the `INDEX` part of `1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1` (aka `jnxOperatingEntry`).

You can find the official documentation on this [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/verification/cpu-utilization-using-mib.html)

Comment: Can you recommend a specific SNMP book or other resource that describes tables in detail?

Comment: @Omnifarious many might have got started with "Essential SNMP". There are other in-depth books.